# Django Error ''Field 'id' expected a number but got <Transfernews: Transfernews object (1)>.''

Tags: django

I am getting this error when trying to submit `comments`. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

My models.py:

```
class Transfernews(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    player_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    player_description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transfernews = models.ForeignKey(Transfernews, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.transfernews.player_name, self.user.username)
```

My forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

My views.py:

```
def transfer_targets(request):
    transfernews = Transfernews.objects.all()
    news = request.POST.get("transfer_id", None)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        new_comment.transfernews_id = Transfernews.objects.get(id=news)
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect(request.path_info)
    return render(request, 'transfernews.html', {'transfernews': transfernews, 'form': form})
```

My html file:

```
{% for transfer in transfernews %}
  <div>Comment and let us know your thoughts</div>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="transfer_id" value="{{ transfer.id}}">
    <div class="bg-alert p-2">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start">
            
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 text-right">
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm shadow-none" type="submit">Post comment</button>
            
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ml-1 shadow-none" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view you should work with:

```
new_comment.transfernews_id = news
```

or:

```
new_comment.transfernews = Transfernews.objects.get(id=news)
```

but the latter is less efficient since you make an extra database query.

You thus can rewrite the view to:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def transfer_targets(request):
    transfernews = Transfernews.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            news = request.POST['transfer_id']
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.transfernews_id = news
            form.save()
            return redirect(request.path_info)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'transfernews.html', {'transfernews': transfernews, 'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: When I'm trying to add a comment now, it says `Method Not Allowed (GET): /transfernews/`

Comment: @Abrar: you should only do that if the view should only work with a POST request. If you work with this with both a GET request *and* a POST request, then the `@require_POST` should not be used.

Comment: Now that I've removed that line, it says `MultiValueDictKeyError at /transfernews/
'transfer_id'`